# How to restrict restrict remote administration software to one domain name?

Tags: ssh, security, dns, webserver

I currently have a server hosting a number of websites on a debian server. I understand that all my domain names share the same IP so any of them will grant me access through SSH, but I was wondering if there was a way to keep the other domain names from letting me into the server. I was hoping this was possible for decreasing surface area for a potential attack.

Answer (score 0):

you have tagged this webserver, so I'm assuming your talking about a website.

surely you already have the hostnames configured in apache to serve different content depending o the domain name used... just add another domain name for the admin stuff,  if you want to be tricky  don't put it in DNS just add it to the hosts file on the computers you use for admin.

ssh deals in ip addresses only, you could shify the ssh server to a different port number, that will hide you from shotgun portscans, just add a host section in your ssh.conf specifying the new port number and acces will just as easy for you.

Comment: I have configured apache to server up different websites for different names, but could you elaborate on "...don't put it in the DNS just add it to the hosts file on the computers you use for admin."

I will definitely move ssh  to a different port  and work on ssh.conf. Thanks for your quick response.